# Storing New Record Through Pivot Table In Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I 'm trying to create a new record when I submit my form data from my front end and I am struggling to wrap my head around how I can do it. I've looked for examples and have had no luck yet in finding something. So I am submitting data for a new engagement and my engagements share a pivot table relationship with tasks. Here is the relationship structure.

1. **User** hasMany **Tasks**
2. **Task** belongsTo **User**
3. **Client** hasMany **Engagements**
4. **Engagement** belongsTo **Client**
5. **Task** belongsToMany **Engagements** (and of course vise versa)

If I submit data to **store a New Engagement and I also want to store a New Task at the *same time*** I am struggling to understand what method I should use to accomplish this.

I do understand that I need the Engagement and Task to exist prior to the pivot table being populated.

**EngagementsController.php** (to store a new engagement)

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'client_id' => 'required|integer',
        'return_type' => 'required|string',
        'year' => 'required|string',
        'status' => 'required|string',
        'assigned_to' => 'required|string',
        'done' => 'required|boolean'
    ]);

    $engagement = Engagement::create([
        'client_id' => $request->client_id,
        'return_type' => $request->return_type,
        'year' => $request->year,
        'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
        'status' => $request->status,
        'done' => $request->done,
    ]);

    return response($engagement, 201);
}
```

After it runs the `$engagement = Engagement` I am wondering If I can use the data for the `assigned_to` field for both the **Engagement** and the **Task** like this?

```php
$engagement = Engagement::create([
    'client_id' => $request->client_id,
    'return_type' => $request->return_type,
    'year' => $request->year,
    'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
    'status' => $request->status,
    'done' => $request->done,
]);

$data = $request->assigned_to;
$task->tasks()->create($data);
```

**Engagement Model**

```php
class Engagement extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =
    [
        'client_id',
        'return_type',
        'year',
        'assigned_to',
        'status',
    ];
    public function client() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task', 'engagement_task', 'engagement_id', 'task_id');
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
    }

}
```

**Task model**

```php
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function engagements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Engagement', 'engagement_task', 'task_id', 'engagement_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `$task = Task::create(['user_id' => $request->get('assigned_to')])`.

Next up you need to [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) the task to the engagement, `$engagement->tasks()->attach($task->id);`

By the way, you can clean up your controller a bit by validating the data in a [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation).

Next you can create your engagement, by `$engagement = Engagement::create($engagementRequest->validated())`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Thijs Bouwes, I have implemented the `Task::create` and I am getting the following alarm `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:` do you know what would be causing this?

Comment: Is the `$request->get('assigned_to')` a valid user id, what exists in your users table?

Comment: It appears that the issue was the id was incorrect. I am now getting a correct response. Thank yo for the help!